# Is it smart to design a command and control server, that will monitor system resources and spin up/spin down servers at times of peak? 

Tags: cloud-computing, hadoop

I am building an application that will be modular, in a way that it will be a set of separate systems communicating with each other. It uses Hadoop on all systems, and HBase on 3 of the 4.

Scaling will only be an issue on the non Hbase system, it uses it's own NoSQL like system. It will be a client facing system, and is very memory intensive, so each server can handle a limited number of users, before drastically dropping performance. All 4 systems have Zookeeper procedures & options built in.

Is it smart to design a command and control server, that will monitor system resources and spin up/spin down servers at times of peak? Would that set me up for failure, since if it faults the whole system can fail? How hard would it be to automate a task like that for Hadoop?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be smart?

Comment: The biggest problem I can see is creating a single point of failure at the C&C server. Which I'm sure there would be a way to overcome, I'm just not sure how. Only way I can think is protecting against physical failure by replicating across regions, but that wouldn't protect against software failure. The software I assume can somehow be health-checked, but I have no idea where I would even begin on designing a health check.

Comment: Sounds like "health check" would be a good thing to solve before designing how bad health should be handled.

Answer (score 3):

At a basic level, you have to have something in place in order to scale up / down the size of your environment.

In your application's infancy, you'll provide that "something."  As you receive feedback from your systems (or more likely from your users complaining about your systems), you'll increase the capacity of the environment.

Automating that manual process is an excellent idea.

I would recommend designing an asynchronous method for querying your system nodes.  An asynchronous update will allow your C&C (command and control) center to keep operating even when a queried node is buried under load or has completely gone down.

But I'll contradict myself by mentioning [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) and [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNMP) as two technologies to consider if you don't want to roll everything yourself.

If you're concerned about your C&C center going down, then the next level will be to setup redundancy between two or more C&C centers.  There are a number of schemes that you can use to minimize overhead in querying nodes.  I think this is beyond the scope of your question, so I won't delve into the details and will be content with having brought it up.

You are at risk of logic flaws within the C&C center.  But if you work through the logic diagram, you'll see you're either better or or no worse than you would have been otherwise.

- C&C good, nodes good == you're good
- C&C good, nodes fail == C&C fixes problem with more resource
- C&C fail, nodes fail == you have resource starvation, but no worse than the case of the nodes failing anyway.

If your health monitor gets really good, it can send warning signals to the C&C center instead of outright error states.  The C&C can then have special logic to wait for the "all-clear" from that node.  If the all-clear doesn't arrive in a set amount of time, the C&C server can automatically spin up more nodes knowing that the troubled node never made it out of the danger zone.

Comment: Thank you, that seems more or less what I was looking for. So basically if I understand correctly, each server will periodically ping the C&C center, and if C&C notices a ping didn't come in within a certain set of parameters it'll consider the server dead

Comment: @user60812 - that would be a good first start.  ICMP / SNMP give you the ability to pass data along as well.  So the next stage would be to indicate # of users, CPU time, Mem Util, etc... Whatever you've correlated with your node servers getting overloaded is good for the C&C to track.  After that, you can start providing predictive correction such as when most of your nodes are near capacity but not fully overloaded then that would be a good time to spin up some more systems.